# Setting .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, innerhtml

I am developing a Firefox extension which need to change some values on a specific `<div>`.

I try to inject this into the DOM by tying this into the URL bar:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('c4d9b2819218742680841961_input').innerHTML = 'foo'
```

The  value do change but then the whole page become blank quickly expect the `<div>`.

How can I avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is acting on the return value for of your code. Wrapping it in a `void()` will suppress this. This should work>

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('c4d9b2819218742680841961_input').innerHTML = 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var elt = document.getElementById('c4d9b2819218742680841961_input');
var textLength = elt.firstChild.length;
elt.firstChild.replaceData(0,textLength,'foo');
```